# Scrollbar to bottom QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QTableWidget that is filled in realtime.
I use the function scrollToBottom() to always see the last information displayed by my table.

It worked well when the size of my différents rows are unchanged.
But sometimes I receive informations that increase the size of my row and the problem is that my table display them like if they were regular rows and with that problem the user can't see the entire row.

If someone already had this problem how did you solve it ?

If it is not clear let me know.

Comment: Does the insertion of a new row execute on the main thread or does it execute on a background thread? If it executes on a background thread then you can get an error where it does not calculate the geometry of the current insertion in a reasonable time, and the scroll to bottom will only scroll to that inaccurate computed value.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with ListView in qml but also with QListWidget. I had to implement a messanger list which added messages dynamically. I still couldn't find a proper solution but I figured out the problem. Your QTableWidget doesn't know how to resize "invisible" row. It approximates the rows size in respect to the visible rows size. I tried to implement custom QListWidget and overwrite the drawing function but couldn't make it work. At that moment I used Qt5.4, I don't know if the issue is solved in the latest versions.

However, one solution is to create html content and display it on a WebView. It's not the most elegant solution but theoretically it should work like a charm.

Comment: Thank you for your answer i will look in this direction

Comment: I spent more than 4 weeks to draw the conclusion that webview is more appealing to my problem.